# .NET - Changing http request type in controller is not being reflected

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have this endpoint in my controller:

```
[Route("api/users")]
[ApiController]
public class CreateAppuserController : ControllerBase
{
    // POST: api/users
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task CreateAppuser([FromBody] Request request)
    {
        return;
    }
}
```

I expect to be able to call it using a POST request because it has the [HttpPost] attribute but it isn't working. I was testing a bit before and changing the attribute to something like Delete, Put, Get etc... but the same issues were happening. My last attempt was changing it to HttpDelete which somehow worked and I can now make a DELETE request. However, as you can see in the code above, it is a POST request right now, but I get a 405 Method Not Allowed error when I try it with POST. Meanwhile if I use DELETE, it still somehow works even though that's the attribute the controller method had around 5 server restarts earlier...

Here is an image from swagger too:
[image: An image from Swagger page]

**UPDATE: It was just a random Visual Studio glitch. I restarted it and it worked.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested code changes in other parts of the project and they weren't being reflected either, so it seems like Visual Studio was just glitching. I closed the project and restarted Visual Studio and it works fine now.